# Cheetah requires Python module Cheetah 2.1.0 or newer - laucnhing sickbeard

Tags: python, python-2.7, version, cheetah

I am trying to use sickbeard on a mac via terminal.

I have installed the latest version pf python (homebrew), then installed cheetah (git then python setup.py install). when finally i try to:

**python sickbeard.py** I get this message:

**Sorry, requires Python module Cheetah 2.1.0 or newer.**

what's wrong with that? Cheetah version is 3.0.0 python is 2.7. 
Thanks :)

-edit

looking into sickbeard.py :

```
# Check needed software dependencies to nudge users to fix their setup
import sys
if sys.version_info < (2, 5):
    sys.exit("Sorry, requires Python 2.5, 2.6 or 2.7.")
```

checking sys:

```
2.7.13 (default, Apr  4 2017, 08:47:57) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)]
```

there it is:

```
try:
    import Cheetah
    if Cheetah.Version[0] != '2':
        raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    sys.exit("Sorry, requires Python module Cheetah 2.1.0 or newer.")
except:
    sys.exit("The Python module Cheetah is required")
```

and **cheetah version** tells 3.0.0, that makes a lot of sense to me =\

Comment: Can you show that sickbeard.py or at least the code that checks Cheetah's version?

Comment: @phd adding info to original post

Comment: That code only checks for Python version. There have to be code that checks Cheetah.

Comment: edited again, soz @phd

Comment: I made it work just changing it to '3', that was easy, the question now is: was that a mistake or shouldn't it be running on cheetah 3?

Comment: Cheetah3 was released in May 2017 after about 5 years hiatus. Not all projects are updated for CT3. But CT3 should be a completely compatible drop-in replacement. In case of problems — please report.

Comment: Please read the description for a tag before applying it to your question. The [tag:git] tag is for questions about Git usage and workflows, not programming questions that happen to involve a Git repo. (I've [edited](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question to remove it.)

Comment: my bad @ScottWeldon

Comment: No problem. To be fair, [the tag excerpts are not very visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114/269535) unless you know what you're looking for.

Comment: For future reference: I changed the file `/usr/share/sickbeard/SickBeard.py` line `27` from `if Cheetah.Version[0] != '2':` to `if Cheetah.Version[0] < '2':`. That fixes the problem and should work as long as future Cheetah versions are compatible drop-in as well.